# How to integrate reactJS app with Google Cloud Functions and Cloud Run with authentication enabled?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I'm developing a reactJS app that will run in browser. I want to make request from that app to services deployed in Google Cloud Run and Google Cloud Functions, both with authentication enabled, but I don't know how to authenticate requests.

I have a Service Account credentials with permissions to invoke those services but I cannot use default credentials due to reactJS environment variables names and I cannot use the NodeJS Google Cloud SDK.

How can I authenticate request to Cloud Functions/Cloud Run from reactJS apps outside of Google Cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use client side authentication mechanism. [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth) works very well, and you have the Google Cloud version name [Google Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform).

---

**EDIT 1**

If your user aren't authenticated, you can't use authentication services. You should want to limit the access, the cost, the abuse of your Cloud Functions and Cloud Run services. For that, you need to use an [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway), such as Google Cloud API Gateway, or a more entreprise grade with [APIGee](https://cloud.google.com/apigee).

You can also use a [HTTPS Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) in [front of Cloud Functions or Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) and activate [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor) to prevent attacks on your service (but it's not a rate limit).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a tutorial I can follow for Firebase and Google Identity? My reactJS app doesn't need to authenticate users, just authenticate request to Cloud Functions and Cloud Run, so I can´t use emails or user ids.

Comment: Ok, so it's different. I updated my answer